# Rails: Create Model with multiple belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database, relationship

I searched for quite a long time and couldnt find that problem.

```
user.erb
     has_many :workouts
     has_many :result_units

workout.erb
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :sets

set.erb
   belongs_to :workout
   has_one :result_unit

result_unit.erb
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :set
```

[image]

1 possible Solution is that ResultUnit dont belong to User. But the question is then how much performance it will cost to query User.workouts.all.sets.all.resultunits.all

How could i create a new ResultUnit for User and Set?

Answer (score 3):

This is a case for using a has_many :through association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Running `User.workouts.all.sets.all.resultunits.all` will result in numerous queries being executed.  A has_many :through however, will execute only a single query and allow the database to optimize the joins between tables.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
  has_many :sets, through: :workouts
  has_many :result_units, through: :sets
end
```

Comment: You'd have to set up the chain of has_many :through associations.  I updated the answer with a snippet showing this.

Comment: okay thanks. could i now create a new result_unit with User.workouts.first.sets.first.resultunit.create() ?

Comment: Yeah, that would work (though `User` would have to be named differently in that statement to avoid conflicts with the class name).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't understand your problem 100%.. but I'm gonna have a stab at it and feel free to downvote if it's not right.

```
class User
  has_many :workouts
  has_many :result_units

  has_many :sets, through: :workouts

  # User.first.workouts
  # User.first.result_units
  # User.first.sets

end

class Workout
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :sets

  # Workout.first.user
  # Workout.first.sets

end

class ResultUnit
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :set

  # ResultUnit.first.user
  # ResultUnit.first.set

end

class Sets
  belongs_to :workout
  has_one :result_unit

  # Set.first.workout
  # Set.first.result_unit

end
```

Comment: I want to create a ResultUnit with member_id and set_id :)